# The conflict occurred in database "X", table "dbo.Y", column 'ld'

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, syntax-error

I'm trying to get a certain amount of animals that have the most comments once I try to delete one of them so I'm getting an error of:
SqlException: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint "FK__Comments__Animal__2EDAF651". The conflict occurred in database "PetShop", table "dbo.Comments", column 'AnimalId'. The statement has been terminated.
I want to make it possible that if I delete then you will move on to the next in line

My Controller for disply:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
    {
        var animal = _context.Animals.Include(c => c.Comments).OrderByDescending(c => c.Comments.Count).Take(2);
        return View(await animal.ToListAsync());

    }
```

My Controller for Delete:

```
 public async Task<Animal> DeleteAnimal(int id)
    {
        var comment = await _context.Comments.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Comments.Remove(comment!);
        var animal = await _context.Animals.FindAsync(id);
        _context.Animals.Remove(animal!);
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        return animal!;
    }
```

My Context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {

        modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasOne(d => d.Animal)
                .WithMany(p => p.Comments)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.AnimalId)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
                .HasConstraintName("FK__Comments__Animal__2EDAF651");
        });

        modelBuilder.Entity<Category>(entity =>
        entity.HasData(
         new { CategoryId = 1, Name = "Dogs" },
         new { CategoryId = 2, Name = "Cats" },
         new { CategoryId = 3, Name = "Birds" },
         new { CategoryId = 4, Name = "Rabbits" },
         new { CategoryId = 5, Name = "Hamsters" }
        )
        );

        modelBuilder.Entity<Animal>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasData(
            new { AnimalId = 1, Name = "Shoko", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-1).AddDays(-12), Description = "Friendly and loyal", CategoryId = 1, PhotoUrl = "ShokoDog.jpg" },
            new { AnimalId = 2, Name = "Bamba", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-2).AddMonths(-2).AddDays(-3), Description = "Furry and neutered", CategoryId = 2, PhotoUrl = "BambaCat.jpg" },
            new { AnimalId = 3, Name = "Regev", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-3).AddDays(-3), Description = "Speak", CategoryId = 3, PhotoUrl = "RegevBird.jpg" },
            new { AnimalId = 4, Name = "Humi", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-3).AddMonths(-4).AddDays(-7), Description = "Cute and furry", CategoryId = 4, PhotoUrl = "HumiRabbit.jpg" },
            new { AnimalId = 5, Name = "Tommy", BirthDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-1).AddMonths(-7).AddDays(-9), Description = "Love to play in the facilities", CategoryId = 5, PhotoUrl = "TommyHamster.jpg" });
        });
        OnModelCreatingPartial(modelBuilder);
    }
```

Comment: Show us your onModelCreating

Comment: i did it i edit my post

Comment: You've changed your post since answers were provided. This should be avoided. Also, I'm not sure you're loading the correct comment for delete; it would be unusual for a comment and an animal to have the same id. If you're going to load an animal and related comments so they can all be deleted, you can use Include. if loading comments without animals, Comments.Find() should probably be swapped for `Where(c => c.AnimalId == id)`

Comment: I do want to load an animal and related comments so they can all be deleted,
But I can not because in remove is asking for one entity
`var animal = _context.Animals.Include(c => c.Comments);
            _context.Animals.Remove(animal!);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return animal!;`

Comment: @CaiusJard I tried to do with clear
but i got error: InvalidOperationException: The association between entity types 'Animal' and 'Comment' has been severed, but the relationship is either marked as required or is implicitly required because the foreign key is not nullable. If the dependent/child entity should be deleted when a required relationship is severed, configure the relationship to use cascade deletes. Consider using 'DbContextOptionsBuilder.EnableSensitiveDataLogging' to see the key values.

Comment: Make your Comment.AnimalId nullable

Comment: i did it: **public int? AnimalId { get; set; }** in the comment class and i get error: **SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'AnimalId', table 'PetShop.dbo.Comments'; column does not allow nulls. UPDATE fails. The statement has been terminated.**

Comment: Sorry, the "or" before was a misdirection; i should have said "and"; set `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)`, and revert the `int?` change if you're not reflecting the same in the DB

Comment: @CaiusJard I do not understand what this code is and where I'm supposed to put it can you explain to me please? **.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)**

Comment: It's in the onmodelcreating, for the Comment entity. If you Ctrl-F for "OnDelete" on this page, you'll see it

Comment: It works thanl you so much! how I can mark this answer

Comment: Give the accept to Karlis; I walked you through their option 2 but they posted the advice first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to remove a parent Animal and related child Comments

To expand on Karlis' suggestions:

1. You have models and context as posted in the question (it's a bit problematic because you say to EF to set null, but the code and DB won't accept null) but you can do:

```
    var a = context.Animals.Include(a => a.Comments).Find(id):
    context.Comments.RemoveRange(a.Comments);
    context.Animals.Remove(a);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

This explicitly removes the comments then the animal

2. Change the context to use `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientCascade)` then you can do:

```
    var a = context.Animals.Include(a => a.Comments).Find(id):
    context.Animals.Remove(a);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

This causes EF to implicitly remove  the comments it knows about when you tell it explicitly to remove the animal

3. Change the DB's foreign key to do an ON DELETE CASCADE, and change `.OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)` then you can skip downloading the Comments (no include):

```
    var a = context.Animals.Find(id):
    context.Animals.Remove(a);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

This causes the DB to remove the comments (EF doesn't know about them) when EF instructs to delete the animal

---

Broadly speaking, these are in order of "how bad of a mistake could you make" from "not very" to "quite a lot"

Answer (score 1):

The error message reads that you are deleting Animal, which has comments associated. You should do one of the following:

1. Remove comments associated with a particular Animal before deleting the Animal.
2. Check EF configuration for cascade on delete
3. Alter FK to have cascade on delete (it depends on whether you are using a database-first or code-first approach)

I would go for the first approach because cascade on delete may be dangerous and silently remove unintentionally referenced data.

Comment: I tried to make suggestion number 1,If you can look again at the post that was updated in the delete function but I get another error: ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null. (Parameter 'entity')